# Django registration unable to show welcome page

Tags: python, django, bitbucket, django-login

I'm quite new to Django/Python. I used [bitbucket's](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/27bccd108cde/docs/quickstart.rst#id1) **Django registration guide**. I've done all the required things. I'm able to login in [database gets updated] and signup correctly, but an error is displayed after logging in. 
the `settings.py` file has:
`ROOT_URLCONF = 'myhandbook.urls'` and my `urls.py` has :

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
)
```

I've mentioned the `url` part as the error is regarding `urls`. I'm getting a `Page Not Found (404)` error.

There's a part **Setting up URLs** in [bitbucket's](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/27bccd108cde/docs/quickstart.rst#id1) documentation that I'm unable to understand, and have tried many things to correct it.

Comment: What is your url after login? Does it exist in your urlpatterns?

Comment: @sneawo: The url for login is `localhost:8000/accounts/login/`. After logging in, the url is `localhost:8000`. This shows an error that the `url` doesn't exist. I don't know how to correct it, as I did follow all the steps from `Bitbucket`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add url for home page. For example:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="home.html"), name='home'),
    (r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
)
```

Then you can replace it with your view.